# Cannot find module "./foo.css" when using webpack as script

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

I'm need to use webpack as a script (not the typical config file) and be able to support css imports, however webpack/style-loader does't seem to be able to load a css import when it's outside the root directory.

**directoryA/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "poc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "poc.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "style-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

**directoryA/poc.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

let appPath = process.env.PWD;

webpack({
  entry: path.join(appPath, 'app.js'),
  context: appPath,
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.join(appPath, 'out'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  }
}).run(() => {
  console.log("done");
});
```

**directoryB/app.js**

```
import './foo.css';
```

**directoryB/foo.css**

```
body {   background-color: blue; }
```

**directoryB/out/index.html**

```
<html>
  <head><script src="app.js"></script></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

steps to replicate:

```
cd directoryB/
node ../directoryA/poc.js
```

then open directoryB/out/index.html in the browser

- result: "Error: Cannot find module "./foo.css"
- expected: loading css style and getting a blue page

Note that, if out/index.html , app.js and foo.cs are inside directoryA instead, then running node poc.js actually yields the expected result, however outside, webpack or style-loader can't seem to find the file (note: also tried to use the `modules:` directive. both cases work if using importing a js file)